# facebook application, inviting friends after the completion of status update feature

Tags: facebook, event-handling, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am making a facebook application, everything seems done.
here is the sample flow(index.php):

1. seekpermission.php
2. processinfo.php
3. generateresult.php
4. poststatus.php(the javascript way as told in the documentation)
5. invitefriends.php(the javascript way as told in the documentation)

hope the names are self explanatory. 
the trouble is the dialogue to update status and invite friends comes almost parallely, but what i want is once the user publishes/skips the status message only then should the dialogue of invite friends should come. here is what i tried but it is not working, please help thanks!

```
 FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'name goes here',
        link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/****/',
        picture: '<?php echo $imageurl; ?>',
        caption: 'here is caption',
        description: 'the description',
        message: '<?php echo $charecter; ?>'
    },
    function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('<?php include "invitefriends.php"; ?>');

    } else {

    alert('<?php include "invitefriends.php"; ?>');

 }
```

here is the invitefriends.php

```
<body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
   </script>
   <script>
     FB.init({ 
       appId:'2****', cookie:true, 
       status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
       message: 'Folks check out my new facebook app!! visit http://apps.facebook.com/**** '});
   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: This should work. I have used this before. Maybe the problem is with how the code looks after the php files are imported. Can you maybe post the content of the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a weird way to accomplish a simple task:
You can combine step 4 & 5 in one step:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'name goes here',
        link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/****/',
        picture: '<?php echo $imageurl; ?>',
        caption: 'here is caption',
        description: 'the description',
        message: '<?php echo $charecter; ?>'
    },
    function(response) {
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Folks check out my new facebook app!! visit http://apps.facebook.com/**** '});
        /* if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('<?php include "invitefriends.php"; ?>');

        } else {

            alert('<?php include "invitefriends.php"; ?>');

        } */
    }
)
```

As you can see no need for the `if else` since you will force the invite anyway!

Now if you really need to use your approach, then you may use something like (in the `response`:

```
location.href='<?php echo 'path/to/invitefriends.php';
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
Most likely **ALL** your 5 steps can be combined in **ONE** file, this is better because:

1. You don't need to load and initialize the JS-library **FIVE** times!
2. Will be a better user experience instead of loading each time
3. You can wrap all the Facebook Calls in JS functions and just call each one in the response of the previous one!

Comment: thnx i faour for the reply i implemented it an it does work, but again i get stuck, this time because if pop-up is blocked in browser the status update pop up dialogue does not work. do you have any work around for it. please help, its the last step!

Comment: @RahulSharma: is `FB.ui` considered a "pop-up" in first place?! I would suggest you ask another questions with screenshots if possible.

Comment: here you go : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387381/facebook-application-dialogue-to-publish-on-users-wall-using-javascript-api-p

Comment: ifaour im still stuck and waiting for your answer