# Facebook application, dialogue to publish on user's wall, using Javascript API, pop-up blocked in browsers

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events, popup-blocker

I am using JS-API to generate a dialogue which asks for permission to publish the status message generated by my Application. Given below is the screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image: THE POP-UP which gets blocked by browsers]

Here is the code:

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

I use the sample JS code as told in the documentation and it works well if pop-ups are not blocked in the browser settings. but without status message being displayed there's no utility of the app!

Please help; I'm stuck at the last stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it's bothering you. If the user is blocking FACEBOOK pop-up then it's his loss!

Anyway, if you really need to handle all cases, then you can choose a different way. Have a read of the [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

What you could do is when you are done from the previous step you redirect your page to the Facebook feed method so it'll open as a page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

The important part to change here is the `app_id` and `redirect_uri`, so your code would look like:

```
...
previous code
...
inside previous code success response
...
var url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?" +
            "app_id=" + YOUR_APP_ID + "&" +
            "link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&" +
            "picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&" +
            "name=Facebook%20Dialogs&" +
            "caption=Reference%20Documentation&" +
            "description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&" +
            "message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&" +
            "redirect_uri=" + YOUR_REDIRECT_URI;
top.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. It brings up the Feed Dialog for me. Your problem is somewhere else. Did you add the `<div id="fb-root"></div>`? Make sure it is at the top of the page just after the `<body>` tag.

Also make sure you are loading the FB Javascript SDK properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code 
you have forget to add display property

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     display: 'popup',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```